# What does it exactly mean that finite linear combination to be dense?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

This phrase comes up over and over again when studying Hilbert space, and since I don't have the strongest background in linear algebra, the statement like "finite linear combination of elements in the orthonormal basis is dense in $\mathbb{H}$. I am not totally sure what it means.

I think it means that is spans the whole space, but could someone help me understand how spanning the whole space relates to the concept of denseness?

Thanks!

Comment: The point here is that often a set of vectors does *not* span the entire space, but does span a *dense subspace*.  For example, consider the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over the field of rationals $\mathbb{Q}$.  The span of $\{1\}$ would be all rational numbers, not all of $\mathbb{R}$, and this span would be dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: One comment is that you really need to be more careful with the language! You have never seen the phrase ""finite linear combination is dense". You've seen the phrase "the finite linear combination$s$ _are_ dense". It actually makes a difference - you're trying to understand what the phrase means, and that's impossible with your version, because your version really makes no sense.

Comment: for $L_2$ functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual $||.||_2$ norm, the finite linear combinations of $(e^{i \omega x}e^{-x^2})_{\omega \in \mathbb{R}}$ are dense while only infinite linear combinations of $(x^k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ are (this example is bad because the $x^k$ are not  elements of $L_2$)

Answer (score 2):

A subset $A$ of a topological (or in particular metric) space $X$ is dense if its closure is $X.$ In a metric space (and a Hilbert space is a metric space) this is equivalent to the condition that every element of $X$ is the limit of some convergent sequence with its elements in $A.$

The word "span" is already contained in "finite linear combination of elements." The missing part is the limit process. Not every element of the Hilbert space needs to be a finite linear combination of elements in the orthonormal basis, but at least it is a limit of a sequence of such combinations.

The nice part about Hilbert spaces, then, is that this sequence can be chosen as the partial sums of some series, so that every element of the Hilbert space can be written as an "infinite linear combination" of the basis vectors.

Take good care with the word "basis", though: what is usually called an orthonormal basis of a Hilbert space is *not* necessarily a basis in the linear algebra sense. The former is called a "Schauder basis" and the latter, if the contrast is important, a "Hamel basis."

Answer (score 2):

Not quite; it means that for any element $x$ in the Hilbert Space and for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an element $s$ in the span such that
$$|x-s| < \epsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

The direct sum $H=E\oplus \mathbb C$ (or $\mathbb R$) define an hyperplan $E$. This $E$ is a maximal subespace of $H$ and is the kernel of a linear form $f:H\to \mathbb C$ (or $\mathbb R$) i. e. $E=f^{-1}(\{0\})$.

A typical case of subspace dense is given when $f$ is not continuous: in fact $\bar E$ is still a subspace of $H$ (by continuity of the sum and product by scalars in $H$) so $E\subset \bar E\subset H$; it follows $\bar E=H$ because $E$ is maximal. The fact that $E$ is all the linear combinations of its elements is going by its structure of vectorial space.